# Modal does not closes using jQuery due to VueJS

Tags: jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-4

In `index.blade.php`, I have this:

```
<div id="books_listing" class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <p>Book suggestions has been enabled.</p>
        <span class="status-close"><b>&times;</b></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `app.js` file there is this some code like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('books_listing')) {
    const bookForm = new Vue({
        el: '#books_listing',
        data: {
          // some data
        },

        methods: {
          // some methods
        },

        mounted: function() {
          // something  
        }
    });
}
```

Also, below in the same `app.js` file, there is this code:

```
$('.status-close').on('click', function(){
    console.log('here');
    let wrapper = $(this).closest('.alert');
    wrapper.fadeOut(500);
});
```

When I click on the close button on the modal, it does not close. What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `span` may be recreated by Vue then your listener will be gone. You can check the listener by right click on that element, choose `Inspect`. In `Elements` tab on you right (or bottom), choose `Event Listeners` tab. If it still there, may be it caused by other reasons.

By the way, I would recommend you to add event listener by using Vue instead.

```
<div id="books_listing" class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <p>Book suggestions has been enabled.</p>
    <span class="status-close" @click='close'><b>&times;</b></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And

```
new Vue({
  el: '#books_listing',
  methods: {
    close: function () {
      let wrapper = $(this.$el).find('.alert');
      wrapper.fadeOut(500);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a few minutes ago, my friend solved this problem by moving jQuery code below the VueJs code. He found one more solution, the jQuery code is executed when the $(document) is ready. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also move this into the mounted hook

> mounted (){   $('.status-close').on('click',function({
>        console.log('here');
>        let wrapper = $(this).closest('.alert');
>        wrapper.fadeOut(500);    });      }

so the event will be added only after vue reconstructed the html elements